# Segmentation fault mongoc_cursor_next BSON_ASSERT

Tags: c++, mongodb

I am trying to get the mongoDb c driver running
When I call the the statement `mongoc_cursor_next`the code crashes with Segmentation fault. The reason for that is in the source code of the function, that says `BSON_ASSERT(bson)`. That makes no sense. Please somebody tell me how to `init const bson_t** bson` properly.

```
const Bson* bson; 
while(!mongoc_cursor_error(cursor, &DbWrapper::error) && mongoc_cursor_more(cursor) && mongoc_cursor_next(cursor, &bson)) 
{
    JsonValue* jsonValue = NULL; 
    (*jsonValue) = DbWrapper::convertBsonToJsonValue(bson); 
    payloadList.push_back(jsonValue); 
}
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: >const Bson* bson;
>    while(!mongoc_cursor_error(cursor, &DbWrapper::error) && >mongoc_cursor_more(cursor) && mongoc_cursor_next(cursor, &bson))
>    { JsonValue* jsonValue = NULL;
>  (*jsonValue) = >DbWrapper::convertBsonToJsonValue(bson);
>  payloadList.push_back(jsonValue);
>    }
>}

Comment: pleas post your `payloadList` declaration is it `std::vector<JsonValue *> payloadList`?

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not C, it's C++ and your problem is very obvious, you are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer here

```cpp
JsonValue* jsonValue = NULL;
(*jsonValue) = DbWrapper::convertBsonToJsonValue(bson);
```

this causes a segmentation fault, you should do it this way

```
JsonValue jsonValue;
jsonValue = DbWrapper::convertBsonToJsonValue(bson);
```

the problem is appending it to the `payloadList` vector, may be you should declare it this way

```
std::vector<JsonValue> payloadList;
```

instead of

```
std::vector<JsonValue *> payloadList;
```

Comment: How do you know it crashes when you call `mongoc_cursor_next(cursor, &bson);`?